# Deploying FluorineFx solution to host

Tags: .net, apache-flex, remoting, fluorinefx

I have a dead simple .NET/FluorineFX project to test remoting with Flex, and it works locally when running the development server, however, when I point the flex app to the deployed version on my virtual hosting account, I get a NetConnection error, specifically:

*Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetConnection.Call.BadVersion*

Inspecting request/response reveals the NetConnection call is just returning the gateway.aspx html content. It seems like the remote site must be missing some configuration value for properly handling the application/x-amf header content type.

Any thoughts? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My thought is contact your host and ask if FlourineFX is installed on the server or if it can be installed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't need to be installed on the host, and by pretty sure I mean nothing I have read indicates it needs to be, and I have seen direct assertions that it doesn't. Do you know for a fact that it does?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?  I'm curious if FluorineFX can be deployed in a shared hosting environment and what installation requirements it has.

Answer (score 0):

i faced a similar issue.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734141/website-using-fluorine-fx-borken-during-migration/12745038#12745038)

Turns out all i had to do was to make the app pool run in classic mode instead of integrated mode. the issue was fixed.