# website using fluorine fx borken during migration

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, fluorinefx

we have asp.net website that has started giving following error after migration from win2k3 to win2k8r2

> (mx.messaging.messages::ErrorMessage)#0
>     body = (Object)#1
>     clientId = (null)
>     correlationId = "4D9A6C96-03CB-3175-FFB4-2CF0D4C4D6FE"
>     destination = ""
>     extendedData = (null)
>     faultCode = "Client.Error.MessageSend"
>     faultDetail = "Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion: : url: 'http://subdomain.domain.org/fluorinefx/gateway.aspx'"
>     faultString = "Send failed"
>     headers = (Object)#2
>     messageId = "90010FA4-E69E-3705-8D29-2CF0D65E957B"
>     rootCause = (mx.messaging.events::ChannelFaultEvent)#3
>       bubbles = false
>       cancelable = false
>       channel = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#4
>         authenticated = false
>         channelSets = (Array)#5
>           [0] (mx.messaging::ChannelSet)#6
>             authenticated = false
>             channelIds = (Array)#7
>               [0] "my-amf"
>             channels = (Array)#8
>               [0] (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#4
>             clustered = false
>             connected = false
>             currentChannel = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#4
>             initialDestinationId = (null)
>             messageAgents = (Array)#9
>               [0] (mx.rpc::AsyncRequest)#10
>                 authenticated = false
>                 autoConnect = true
>                 channelSet = (mx.messaging::ChannelSet)#6
>                 clientId = (null)
>                 connected = false
>                 defaultHeaders = (null)
>                 destination = "fluorine"
>                 id = "D967EE11-9117-DE39-E544-2CEF7130B37A"
>                 reconnectAttempts = 0
>                 reconnectInterval = 0
>                 requestTimeout = -1
>                 subtopic = ""
>               [1] (mx.rpc::AsyncRequest)#11
>                 authenticated = false
>                 autoConnect = true
>                 channelSet = (mx.messaging::ChannelSet)#6
>                 clientId = (null)
>                 connected = false
>                 defaultHeaders = (null)
>                 destination = "fluorine"
>                 id = "B1282969-F54C-B538-E4B1-2CF0D4C3CB73"
>                 reconnectAttempts = 0
>                 reconnectInterval = 0
>                 requestTimeout = -1
>                 subtopic = ""
>         connected = false
>         connectTimeout = -1
>         enableSmallMessages = true
>         endpoint = "http://subdomain.domain.org/fluorinefx/gateway.aspx"
>         failoverURIs = (Array)#12
>         id = "my-amf"
>         mpiEnabled = false
>         netConnection = (flash.net::NetConnection)#13
>           client = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#4
>           connected = false
>           objectEncoding = 3
>           proxyType = "none"
>           uri = "http://subdomain.domain.org/fluorinefx/gateway.aspx"
>         piggybackingEnabled = false
>         polling = false
>         pollingEnabled = true
>         pollingInterval = 3000
>         protocol = "http"
>         reconnecting = false
>         recordMessageSizes = false
>         recordMessageTimes = false
>         requestTimeout = -1
>         uri = "http://subdomain.domain.org/fluorinefx/gateway.aspx"
>         url = "http://subdomain.domain.org/fluorinefx/gateway.aspx"
>         useSmallMessages = false
>       channelId = "my-amf"
>       connected = false
>       currentTarget = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#4
>       eventPhase = 2
>       faultCode = "Channel.Connect.Failed"
>       faultDetail = "NetConnection.Call.BadVersion: : url: 'http://subdomain.domain.org/fluorinefx/gateway.aspx'"
>       faultString = "error"
>       reconnecting = false
>       rejected = false
>       rootCause = (Object)#14
>         code = "NetConnection.Call.BadVersion"
>         description = ""
>         details = ""
>         level = "error"
>       target = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#4
>       type = "channelFault"
>     timestamp = 0
>     timeToLive = 0

Following is the configuration information of the old server

win2k3r2 64 bit
iis6
Fluroine fx(1.0.0.15) as shown in add remove programs
Fluroine fx windows service not installed.
FluorineFx.dll 1.0.0.15(present inside bin folder of my website)
FluorineFx.ServiceBrowser.dll 1.0.0.15 (present inside bin folder of my website)

Following is the configuration information of the old server

win2k8r2 64 bit
iis7.5
Fluroine fx(1.0.0.15) as shown in add remove programs
Fluroine fx windows service installed(fluorinefx.exe (1.0.0.13)).
FluorineFx.dll 1.0.0.15 (present inside bin folder of my website)
FluorineFx.ServiceBrowser.dll 1.0.0.15 (present inside bin folder of my website)
Site has its own app pool. App pool is allowing 32 bit applications. idle timeout is 0

There is a "fluorinefx" folder inside the directory both on old and new servers which has gateway.aspx and console.aspx file.

This is the content of console.aspx.cs file

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Console : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Fluorine.aspx");
    }

```
#region Web Form Designer generated code
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    //
    // CODEGEN: This call is required by the ASP.NET Web Form Designer.
    //
    InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e);
}

/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
{    
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);

}
#endregion
```

}

This is the content of "gateway.aspx.cs" file

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Gateway : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
}
```

}
This is my crossdomain.xml file

```
<cross-domain-policy> <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/> <allow-access-from domain="*"/> </cross-domain-policy>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. Turns out all i had to do was to make the app pool run in classic mode instead of integrated mode. the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

this is the content of service-config.xml file inside |c:\websites\subdomain.domain.org\websiteroot\web-inf\flex" folder  

    
        
         -->
         -->

```
<!-- Custom authentication -->
<security>
    <!-- A security constraint requires that a user is authorized before accessing a destination.
    Here you can declare security constraints globally. When several destinations 
    use the same security settings, you should define one security constraint in the 
    security section of the services configuration file and refer to it in each destination.                
    -->
    <!-- 
    <security-constraint id="privileged-users">
        <auth-method>Custom</auth-method>
        <roles>
            <role>admin</role>
            <role>privilegeduser</role>
        </roles>
    </security-constraint>    
     -->

    <!--    
    Custom login command, to check a user's credentials and log a principal into the application server
    A login command must implement the com.TheSilentGroup.Fluorine.Messaging.Security.ILoginCommand interface
    or inherit from com.TheSilentGroup.Fluorine.Messaging.Security.GenericLoginCommand.

    You can use a login command without security constraints defined.
    -->
    <!-- 
    <login-command class="FluorineFx.Security.GenericLoginCommand" server="asp.net"/>
     -->
</security>

<channels>
    <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint uri="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/fluorinefx/Gateway.aspx" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
            <!-- <legacy-collection>true</legacy-collection> -->
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>
    <!--
    <channel-definition id="my-rtmp" class="mx.messaging.channels.RTMPChannel">
        <endpoint uri="rtmp://{server.name}:2037" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.RTMPEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>20</idle-timeout-minutes>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>
    -->
</channels>
```